# is it possible to pass variable from one innerhtml to another innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my snippet which am developing has four inner htmls with javascript now my question is can we get all these data from all and add(if integer) them or concatinate(if string) and dispaly in another div tag

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = 10;
</script>    

<script>
 document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = 20;
</script>

<div id="one">    
</div>

<div id="two">    
</div>

<div id="three">
    now here i want the sum of the both one and two
</div>
```

anyone help me is it possible or not if yes how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would set the `<div id="three">` innerHTML to sum of `<div id="one">` and `<div id="two">`. If you need to just concatenate (you mention both *concatenate* and *sum* in your question, so it's not clear which one you actually need) two innerHTML strings then remove the `parseInt();` functions.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('three').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('one').innerHTML) + parseInt(document.getElementById('two').innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: its working thanks for the replay....but when i use it in two different functions its not working..... like function name(){//i get innerhtml1 1} and function 2{ // innerhtml 2 } //innerhtml3 here not working http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5SCnf/6/

Comment: In the jsfiddle you provided I don't see you using 3 functins so I can't help you much. Can you correct it?

Comment: i my example i need to get those from the different functions is there a way to access those variables of different functions and show the result in last one it shows up onclick.....

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.. Try this

```
 var x = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = 10; 
 var y = document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = 20;
 document.getElementById('three').innerHTML = x + y;    

                        OR   
//Using jQuery
$('#one').html(10);  
$('#two').html(20);   
$('#three').html( parseInt($('#one').text()) +  parseInt($('#two').text()));
```

[Check FIDDLE JAVASCRIPT](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5SCnf/6/)

[Check FIDDLE JQUERY](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5SCnf/7/)

**UPDATED**
Your Markup should look like this

```
<script>
 var x = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = 10;
 var y = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = 20; 
 document.getElementById('three').innerHTML = x + y;    
</script>   

<div id="one">    
</div>

<div id="two">    
</div>

<div id="three">
    now here i want the sum of the both one and two
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest using `.html()` over `.text()`, as the OP is trying to set the innerHTML. I see a jQuery tag in the question, but no jQuery code, i'm not sure if jQuery is what OP wants/needs. Regardless of how the values are set/gotten; the concatenation should stay the same. Also, you're missing some semicolons ;-)

Comment: [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) returns `NaN` if it cannot parse a number, so if both the DIV's contain strings; you're actually trying to concatenate `NaN` + `NaN`!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = x;
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = y;
document.getElementById('three').innerHTML = x+y;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2eT7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML +
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML +
document.getElementById('three').innerHTML +
document.getElementById('four').innerHTML;
```

does it solve ? what kind of question is this ? but the above will only concatenate, if you want to check if its an integer then you goto write a javascript to check if integer.